# Make device silent on local notification swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uilocalnotification, silent

Is it possible in iOS to make the device silent with a local notification? I'm working on an app in which I have to make an iOS device silent for a short time. By this I mean it won't ring for incoming calls, text messages or any other notifications.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: No, there are no public API that would allow you to change the volume/vibrate settings on iOS. Only the user can change these settings.

Comment: okay. got it. thank you.

Comment: i have searched alot not found any way to do this. now its final there is no way.

Comment: I am not sure why you thought Apple would allow you to do this. There is no good reason for doing so

Comment: Im new in notifications while app is not running. I learned alot i just wanna to confirm with others. May be anyones any 3rd api. @Scriptable

Comment: no, cannot be done. even if you managed it somehow Apple would never let you put it on store

Comment: by @rckoenes commit i got it. its not possible. well thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Apple's documentation it won't be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot R&D i reached to the point Apple will not accept even if it is forcefully done. answer is Closed.